# Move series of div to the left with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

A client really wants important content inside a carousel and, while I know they are spawns of the devil himself, I have to do what she wants. I suggested her to always put the keywords visible so the overwhelming majority of customers who will never see the descriptions can still see the keywords.

---

`Keyword_A` | `Keyword_B` | `Keyword_C`

Description of keyword A

**<----- Animation <-----**

`Keyword_B` | `Keyword_C` | `Keyword_A`

Description of keyword B

---

I need to animate the movement of the divs containing the keywords, everything in a responsive way.
I would also like to make every keyword clickable in order to trigger the animation and show the proper description.

Sorry for the silly question, I'm a backend guy and couldn't find an answer lurking around.

Answer (score 0):

if you can add jQuery to you code see this [jQuery cheat sheet](https://oscarotero.com/jquery/) :
you can use the

```
$("#someID").animate(
    options(object),
    time(number),
    callback-function(when animation is done
);
```

hopefully all the `EFFECTS` part with the blue color would be helpful for you